# Using pipes over message queues for message-based communication

Tags: linux, pipe, ipc, message-queue

There is a inter-process communication use case were two related processes need to communicate requests/responses (fixed structure messages) to each other, no prioritization for requests is needed.
According to my understanding since this is a message-based communication it is more convenient to use message queues. But I encountered some implementations that uses pipes (they construct message headers to be able to pack/unpack messages over byte stream).

So my question is, what is the benefit of using pipes over message queues in this use case (or in message-based communication in general), is this just a bad design or there are benefits that overcome the cost of adding code to pack/unpack messages over byte stream?

Comment: `over message queues` Is "message queues" an abstract term in your text, or do you specifically refer to about POSIX `mq_open()` interface? You can implement a "message queue" (i.e. MQTT, for example) over a pipe.

Comment: I refer to POSIX (or System V) message queues

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to make a short table.

| `pipe()` | POSIX `mq_*` |
| --- | --- |
| less resources, simple | more complicated |
| always available just everywhere | needs `CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE` Linux Kernel option |
| easy to use, known and used everywhere | almost forgotten nowadays and specific use cases |
| messages less than PIPE_BUF (`4096` on linux, at least `512`) are guaranteed be written/read in one go | builtin messages boundaries |
| just a fifo | builtin priorities of messages, the most important get's delivered first |
| you can use poll/select | You can't use poll/select. (Except you can *on Linux*, not portable). |
| auto-cleanup | auto-cleanup after unlink() / needs synchronization of processes to do proper cleanup |
| standard way of sharing a channel between `fork`s / is local to the process | can communicate between *unrelated* processes / the name is global, unix permissions access appplies |
| `ulimit -n` (`/etc/security/limits.conf`) limit open file descriptors | `NAME_MAX` limits the name (and `mqd_t` is also file descriptor on linux) |
|  | need to link with `rt` when compiling |
| can be connected to standard streams | requires special `mq_*` interface |
| uses `read`/`write` syscalls | uses special `mq_*` syscall (on Linux) |